# Multiple parameters in Django URLconf

Tags: python, django, parameters, urlconf

Say I want my URLs to have alphanumeric string parameters, where each parameter is separated by a '+' and we have more than 1 parameter. That is, blah.com/1a+2b would be valid, but blah.com/1a or blah.com/1a_2b would not be valid.

So far, in my urls.py, I have:

```
(r'^((\w+)\+)+(\w+)$', 'XXX.views.YYY')
```

and in views.py:

```
YYY(request, name, args*)
```

Anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the string in your URLConf and validate in your view.

```
url(r'^(?P<params_list>(\w+)\+?)+)/$');
```

In your view:

```
def my_view(request, params):
  if not validate_params(params): # validate as you wish
    raise Http404()

  # continue with your view
```

Or, if your view already expects a list, you could write a decorator to take the string, parse it and pass it to your view as a list.